# Does heroku support Ruby's net/sftp library?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sftp

Running Ruby 2.0 on Heroku's cedar stack.

I have a rake task which has the following line:
`require 'net/sftp'`

When I push to Heroku, I receive the following error:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
       Could not detect rake tasks
       ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
       and using the production group of your Gemfile.
       This may be intentional, if you expected rake tasks to be run
       cancel the build (CTRL+C) and fix the error then commit the fix:
       rake aborted!
       LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/sftp
```

I couldn't find any resources saying Heroku does not support `net/sftp`, but this seems to indicate it does not.

Does Heroku support the `net/sftp` library?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add

```
gem "net-sftp"
```

to your Gemfile?